# htaccess - how can I add header set to a specific folder?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to add a speicifc header set to a folder on my website
So i case my URL is as follow:
/kr/example.html

What should be the syntax?

Comment: It's not clear what  you're asking.  Are you asking how to add an HTML header to all HTML files in a folder?  Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: Not at all. I would like to set the following line:             Header set jobs "send  your cv to xxx@gmail.com" to only to the mentioned URL above